# Flask Socket-IO Server Client Not Communicating (with tweepy and twilio)

Tags: python, flask, twilio, flask-socketio

I am trying to have a Flask Server that allows me to launch a tweepy stream and on every message received in the stream listener, it sends that message to a socketio client. The Flask server is at the same time supposed to allow Twilio to post to it, and route that message to the client—so that the client is receiving messages from both Twilio and twitter.

I have been trying to get the server to send messages over to the client for the data incoming from twitter, the code for Twilio works just fine. It sends data over to the client on message receipt. The main loop in tweepy is also not locking up the program—I can test print statements and see tweets and the incoming sms's being printed in the `handle_message(msg)` function asynchronously. I feel like there must be something really simple that I am missing here since the SMS's are emitted to the client, but the incoming tweets are not, even though they are propagating through to the `handle_message(msg)` function. What gives?

**server.py**

```
from flask import Flask, json, request
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import Message, MessagingResponse
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
import tweepy
import json

PATH = '/path/to/credentials/'
with open(PATH, "r") as file:
    credentials = json.load(file)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'abc123'
sio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(credentials['CONSUMER_KEY'], credentials['CONSUMER_SECRET'])
auth.set_access_token(credentials['ACCESS_TOKEN'], credentials['ACCESS_SECRET'])
api = tweepy.API(auth)

class MyListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        print('status')

    def on_data(self, data):
        handle_message(data)

    def on_error(self, status):
        print('error')
        print(status)

stream_listener = MyListener()

# twilio sms route
@app.route('/sms', methods=['POST'])
def sms():
    number = request.form['From']
    message_body = request.form['Body']
    message_data = {"number": number, "msg": message_body}
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    resp.message('Hello {}, you said: {}'.format(number, message_body))
    handle_message(message_data)
    return str(resp)

# flask-socketio stuff
@sio.on('connect')
def connect():
    print('connected')
    sio.emit('client_connected', "you connected")
    search_term = "#mysearchterm"
    stream = tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth, listener=stream_listener)
    stream.filter(track=[search_term], is_async=True)
    sio.emit('client_connected', "the search term is {}".format(search_term))

@sio.on('disconnect')
def disconnect():
    print('Client Diconnected')

@sio.event
def handle_message(message):
    print("This is the message received: ", message)
    sio.emit('handle_message', message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sio.run(app)
```

**client.py**

```
import socketio

client = socketio.Client()

@client.on('client_connected')
def on_connect(message):
    print(message)

@client.on('handle_message')
def message(data):
    print(data)

client.connect('http://localhost:5000/')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem! As I noted in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69752782/flask-socket-io-server-client-not-communicating-with-tweepy-and-twilio#comment123322061_69762014), the issue was with multithreading and passing information between the threads. With tweepy, the parameter `is_async=True`, which in 4.1.0 is `threading=True`, opens up a new thread once the stream is run.

Instead of trying to deal with passing information around, I exploited the extant flask-socketio functionality by [using a local redis server as a message queue](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment.html#emitting-from-an-external-process) (start from the section "Using Multiple Workers" if you are setting this up for the first time, also be sure to install [redis](https://redis.io/topics/quickstart)).

Here is the updated `server.py` code. The `client.py` code remained essentially unchanged:

```
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()
from flask import Flask, json, request
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import Message, MessagingResponse
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
import tweepy
import json

PATH = '/PATH/TO/CREDENTIALS'
with open(PATH, "r") as file:
    credentials = json.load(file)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'abc123'
sio = SocketIO(app, message_queue='redis://', cors_allowed_origins="*")

class MyStream(tweepy.Stream):
    def __init__(self, consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret):
        super(MyStream, self).__init__(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)
        self.stream_sio = SocketIO(message_queue='redis://')

    def on_status(self, status):
        print('status')

    def on_data(self, data):
        json_data = json.loads(data)
        self.stream_sio.emit('handle_message', json_data['text'])
        # TODO: Send along all necessary information

@app.route('/sms', methods=['POST'])
def sms():
    number = request.form['From']
    message_body = request.form['Body']
    message_data = {"number": number, "msg": message_body}
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    resp.message('Hello {}, you said: {}'.format(number, message_body))
    handle_message(message_data)
    return str(resp)
 
@sio.on('connect')
def connect():
    print('connected')
    sio.emit('client_connected', "you connected")
    search_term = "#testingtesting123"
    stream = MyStream(credentials['CONSUMER_KEY'], credentials['CONSUMER_SECRET'],
                           credentials['ACCESS_TOKEN'], credentials['ACCESS_SECRET'])
    stream.filter(track=[search_term], threaded=True)
    sio.emit('client_connected', "the search term is {}".format(search_term))

@sio.on('disconnect')
def disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected')

def handle_message(message):
    sio.emit('handle_message', message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sio.run(app)
```

Comment: Nice solution, I'm glad you worked it out!

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You've decorated the `handle_message` function as `@sio.event` but [as far as I can see in the docs](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client.html#event-callbacks), you should only do that to have the `handle_message` method respond to events on the socket called "handle_message".

I'd start be removing the `@sio.event` decorator.

I'm not a Python expert, but I also wonder whether there is a scope issue here. You define your `MyListener` class and create an instance of it before you define the `handle_message` method. Just to test, can you try emitting to the socket directly within the `on_data` method:

```py
    def on_data(self, data):
        sio.emit('handle_message', data)
```

If that works, consider moving the definition of `handle_message` above the definition of `MyListener`.

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks for the response. I had tried emiting directly from on_data before and it didn't work. I am now guessing that this is actually a threading issue, as I have to put Tweepy into a separate thread with the is_async=True bit. The naming is a little bit confusing there—as it doesn't use asyncio. I decided to change things up and update to the newer version of tweepy in the end. Still, functionally I have the same problem—but now with multithreading! If you have advice (or links) on how to pass data from tweepy and flask which are in separate threads, I would appreciate the help!